# Is there an online drag-and-drop interactive sort simulator?

Tags: resource-request, algorithms

When teaching my students about different sort algorithms, I would like to give them a virtual hand of cards to sort so they can try out an algorithm by dragging and dropping to reorder the cards. Is there an online simulator for this?

I am not asking for a visualization, which demonstrates sort algorithms step-by-step. I am looking for a site where the student has to move the items.

Comment: This is specific enough that I bet it doesn't exist, but also such a cool idea that if it did exist, I would start using it immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a website: https://deck.of.cards/. It doesn't know anything about computer science or sorting, but I was able to use it to demonstrate insertion sort and let my students practice, which is all I needed.

Comment: I wish it had an open-hand option. The 52 card drags and turnovers at the start are a *drag* (ba-dum CH!)